# How to play my own Bedrock Server on PlayStation without PS plus

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition, ps4, networking

I have a Minecraft Bedrock Server running on a spare computer that sits in my living room connected to my local network.

I can see the server in LAN games on my PS4 (which is on the same local network in the living room) but cannot connect as it asks me to purchase PS Plus subscription.

Is there any workaround?

Comment: Are you using a minecraft realm, or a server?

Comment: Both PS4 and Bedrock Server are in my living room connected to the same LAN switch

Answer (score 1):

You can't access any of the modes that allow you to play with other players if you don't have a PlayStation Plus subscription.

It doesn't matter if is via Xbox Live, PSN, LAN or a Dedicated Server, you need PS+ to play even if you are alone in that server.

Comment: should the local network be called on-line? I can easily turn off the internet router and still access local network

Comment: Yes sadly, as that is considered by SIE as "online play". Everything that makes you play with other players in non Free to Play titles is considered online play on PlayStation.